# Complex Id for many-to-many relation in Spring R2DBC

Tags: java, spring-data-r2dbc

I have entity which handles many-to-mane relation between `student` and `tutor` tables where primary key is complex key(`relation_id` and `tutor_id`).

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table("tutor_student")
public class TutorStudentEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column("tutor_id")
    private Long tutorId;
    @Column("student_id")
    private String studentId;
    @Column("status")
    private String status;

}
```

When I want to update record with `ReactiveCrudRepository#save` Spring R2DBC tries to create new record in DB because can not define id.

I know several solutions with JPA like `@EmbeddedId` and `@IdClass`. I tried to do the same here but obviously It is not JPA that is why it has not worked.

What is solution for this case? how Can I configure complex primary key and update record with the help of Spring R2DBC?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use @IdClass to fix this, here is what i came up with

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table("tutor_student")
@IdClass(TutorStudentId.class)
public class TutorStudentEntity {

    @Id
    @Column("relation_id")
    private Long relationId;

    @Id
    @Column("tutor_id")
    private Long tutorId;

    @Column("student_id")
    private String studentId;

    @Column("status")
    private String status;

}
```

StudentId Class Should look like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TutorStudentId implements Serializable {

    private Long relationId;
    private Long tutorId;

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think that for Spring R2DBC we can not use annotations from `javax.persistence` package. As I know annotations from  `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` package should be used. Bu `@Id` should be only one in entity.

Answer (score 0):

`TutorStudentEntity` needs to implement `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable` and have `Persistable::isNew` default to false;

Example given for a `Handler`

```
public class SomeEntity implements Persistable<String> {
    @Transient
    private boolean isNew;
    @Id
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    ...
```

and

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> updateSomeEntity(ServerRequest request) {
    return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(request.bodyToMono(SomeEntity.class)
                    .doOnNext(this::validate)
                    .flatMap(someEntityRepository::save), SomeEntity.class);
}
```

Git repo for above [WebFluxDataR2dbc](https://github.com/karlnicholas/WebFluxDataR2dbc.git)

Comment: I checked and this solution works for entity with single primary key. But how should it work with complex(multiple) primary key?

Comment: It's not supported. If you really want the efficiency of a fully reactive stack then don't mess around with spring data. Use SQL.